# Not getting the desired output for echo command

Tags: shell, shell-script, echo

Below is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVERS="sl20rht00-t"
#SERVERS="shcbrht01-t"
USR="adm-dt-c"
for host in $SERVERS
do
ssh -tt $USR@$host 'sudo cp /etc/sudoers /Backups/sudoers_11thmarch2015; sudo cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /Backups/sshd_11thmarch2015; sudo cat /home/adm-dt-c/denyuser >>  sudo /etc/ssh/sshd_config; sudo /etc/init.d/sshd restart;'
done
exit 0
```

The problem is I'm not able to append the line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` even after the successful execution of the script.

Comment: You can't just throw `sudo` in randomly like a magic spell - it doesn't work like that. In particular `sudo cat /home/adm-dt-c/denyuser >>  sudo /etc/ssh/sshd_config` makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` doesn't work for redirection. You probably now have a `~$USR/sudo` file. Instead of redirect, pipe to a `sudo tee`.

Change this:

```
ssh -tt $USR@$host 'sudo cp /etc/sudoers /Backups/sudoers_11thmarch2015; sudo cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /Backups/sshd_11thmarch2015; sudo cat /home/adm-dt-c/denyuser >>  sudo /etc/ssh/sshd_config; sudo /etc/init.d/sshd restart;'
```

To something like this:

```
ssh -tt $USR@$host 'sudo cp /etc/sudoers /Backups/sudoers_11thmarch2015; sudo cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /Backups/sshd_11thmarch2015; sudo cat /home/adm-dt-c/denyuser | sudo tee -a /etc/ssh/sshd_config > /dev/null; sudo /etc/init.d/sshd restart;'
```